# Understanding the proof of the Compactness principle

Tags: complex-analysis

Consider the following theorem: "For any sequence of analytic inside $D\subset C$ functions from an infinity family $\Phi$ of analytic inside $D$ functions to have a uniformly converging inside $D$ to an analytic function subsequence, it is necessary and sufficient for $\Phi$ to be uniformly bounded inside $D$.". ( https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Compactness_principle )

The proof for necessity goes as follows:

"Suppose $\Phi$ is not uniformly bounded. Then there exists such a closed subset $K\subset D$, that for every real $M>0$ there exists such a function $f(z)\in \Phi$, that $\max_{z\in K}|f(z)|>M$.Then we show that there exists such a sequence $(f_n)$, that $f_n(z_n)\to\infty$.

Then, from the conditions, there exists a subsequence $(f_{n_k})$ of $(f_n)$ that converges uniformly to some analytic function $f$. In particular, there exists $N$, such that for $k>N$, $|f_{n_k}(z)-f(z)|<1$. Hence, $|f_{n_k}(z)|<|f(z)|+1<\max_{z\in K}|f(z)|+1=M<\infty$ for $k>N$. Contradiction with $f_n(z_n)\to\infty$."

I fail to see why $\max_{z\in K}|f(z)|+1=M<\infty$, in other words, why $|f(z)|$ is bounded in $K$. Any help? I know that an analytic function is continuous, and continuous functions are bounded on closed and bounded sets of $C$. But here $K$ seems arbitrary

Edit: sorry. misplaced D with K. now correct.

Comment: Isn't $K$ assumed to be compact?

Comment: @Fimpellizieri oh.  K is closed set! It should read "Then there exists such a CLOSED subset K⊂D". I missed that. but im nto sure if that ensures the boundedness of f on K. 

im not sure why it should be a closed set, though. This proof is from a text in russian

Comment: I think it's very hard to parse your text partly because of the English.

Comment: The EOM article you link to states clearly that $K$ is supposed to be a compact subset of $D$.

Comment: @DanielFischer okay i think taht solves it. it is somehow not mentioned in the the text im reading and tried to translate into english. thank you!